# Can we change wordpress custom walker class first (root) ul tag using PHP by overriding The Walker_Nav_menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-walker

Hey guys using the Wordpress Framework usually I create a custom walker that extends [Walker_Nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/)
in order to make a custom wordpress menu. I did register the Menu location in the functions.php , I did hook up the menu and create a custom_nav_walker and it worked.
 however **I cannot change the main ul root tag to put some inline code up there** using the navwalker php class without using javascript.

So the nav menu html is something like this.

```
<ul id="Root-tag-That-I-want-to-modify" class="vertical medium-horizontal menu dropdown" <!--  I WANT TO ECHO CODE HERE USING PHP --> >
<li id="menu-item-146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-146">
<a href="http://Thelink">Item</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children active has-dropdown menu-item-147"><a href="http://ThesecondLink">submeu</a>
<ul class="0 menu submenu is-dropdown-submenu first-sub vertical"  data-submenu="" role="menu">
<li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-153"><a href="http://anotherlink">submeu item</a> 
</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I tried to override the start_lvl funtion that is inside the Walker class :

```
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
      $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
      $first = ($depth === 0) ? 'first-sub' : '';
      $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"$depth menu submenu is-dropdown-submenu $first vertical\"  data-submenu=\"\" role=\"menu\">\n";
     }
```

> After printing $depth inside the ul tag I found out that this first UL is not processed by this start_lvl

Where in this class can I override the main UL tag, I checked the wordpress call wp_nav_menu array maybe I missed something ??
I am interested in doing this with PHP without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found is [to change the 'menu_class' parameter when instantiating the walker class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters) , Usually you have :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu_class'      => 'vertical medium-horizontal menu dropdown',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new Custom_Walker_Class()  ));
```

To include some extra line-codes example (**data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown" role="menubar'**) I changed it to :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu_class'      => 'vertical medium-horizontal menu dropdown" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown" role="menubar',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new Custom_Walker_Class()  ));
```

Basically it is shipping all the ul tag inline code inside this parameters string. Since it is getting a string (which is supposed to be just the ul tag classes) and wrapping it in quotes to print it as a wrapper for nav elements in the Html.

Ok So far the idea is good but I couldn't escape the  quotes and I ended with some source code like this :

> class=&quot ;vertical medium-horizontal menu dropdown&quot ;  data-responsive-menu=&quot ;  accordion medium-dropdown"  role=&quot ;  menubar&quot ;

What I did to correct things is to :

1. I stored the wp_nav_menu result into some variable
2. I encoded that variable into a string (the &quot ; will become ")
3. I decoded and printed the resulting HTML

   ```
   $db = esc_attr('" ');
   $inlinecode= esc_attr('vertical medium-horizontal menu dropdown' . $db . ' data-responsive-menu=' . $db . ' accordion medium-dropdown' . $db . ' role=' . $db . ' menubar' . $db . ');


   $mainmenu = wp_nav_menu( array(

       'menu_class'      => $inlinecode,
       'echo'            => false,
       'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
       'depth'           => 0,
           'walker'          => new Walker_Primary()
           ));

           $men_encoded = esc_attr($mainmenu);
           echo html_entity_decode($men_encoded);
   ```